# Why can't we embed or upload videos?

Tags: feature-request

There are many times I would love to embed a video from YouTube or even my own.

I am not sure if its the correct place to ask as this section is small; but imagine if we were the first to allow for such a thing.

I think its time to get up to speed with HTML5 capable browsers as movies are native now and so will be graphics.

A simple `<youtube>youtubeid</youtube>` should to the trick. I have seen addons like this in PHPBBForum and works well.

Here is one example to embed a video

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1582/894

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's necessary

Answer (score 2):

Embedded videos are enabled on a per-site basis right now. According to [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/184498) it is currently embedded on.

1. [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), and
2. [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/)

I'll try and see what we have to do to get them embedded, but we are going to need some really good reasons. If you can, it would help if you could join our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) that way we can brainstorm some reasons that we need this.